# Mixing Angular versions

Tags: angular

we have our Angular Module in Version 4.2.3.

Is it possible to import a Feature Module of a higher Angular Version like 5.2.8.

Will this work? Are there any restriction or description how to do that?

Thanks in Advance for your help.
Stephan

Comment: To clarify your question, your app is using Angular v4.2.3 and you want to use a third party package that is using Angular v5.2.8 or you want to create another 'feature mdodule' in your app with a newer version of Angular (5.2.8)?

Comment: I would like to create an own feature module in version 5.2.8 (or 6.0.0) and use it in my own app module version 4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, at this point in time, there can only be one `@angular` set of code in your `node_modules` folder ... that means only one version of Angular can be installed with your application.

There is very little difference between Angular v4.2 and Angular v5.2.8, so there should not be an issue moving all of your code to v5.2.8.

You can use this app: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ to see the specific differences between the versions.

Alternatively, you could build the new feature as a component library following the instructions here: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e But a component library is really meant for reusable pieces of code, not feature modules.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.!